# Source engine - movement code: What is "wishspeed"?

Tags: c++, vector, source-engine

I've been looking into the Source Engine lately. More specifically, the strafing/bunnyhopping sort of movement they have.

https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/56accfdb9c4abd32ae1dc26b2e4cc87898cf4dc1/sp/src/game/shared/gamemovement.cpp#L1779

Here is the actual movement code for the source engine. My question points towards line 1779 and 1784. Here, `wishspeed` is given a value of `wishdir's` magnitude. Although when a vector (`wishdir`) is a normalized vector, wouldn't the magnitude be normalized too? (So it would be a magnitude of 1)

To my understanding that's what happens when something is normalized. If this is true, why is there an if statement of line 1784 with `if ( wishspeed != 0 && **(wishspeed > mv->m_flMaxSpeed)**)`, if wishspeed is 1? Looking further into the code, there's more hinting towards wishspeed not being either 0 or 1, but a higher value.

Could someone explain to me how this is possible?
How can wishspeed be over 1 when it should've been normalized?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the source, but perhaps `VectorNormalize` normalizes the vector but also returns the magnitude prior to the normalization? The normalization would have to calculate the magnitude to do the normalization so I don't think its unlikely that it could return it as a general optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [developer.valvesoftware.com](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Vector#Helper_functions) on `float VectorNormalize(vec)` :

> Divides the vector by its length, normalising it. Modifies the Vector and returns the old length.

`wishspeed` takes the length the `wishdir` had before it was normalized.

Answer (score 2):

On this page the operation is documented:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Vector

VectorNormalize() returns the original length of the vector.